# How to remove/uninstall corrupted winget package?

Tags: windows, package-management, python3, windows-packagemanagement, winget

When I run `winget list python` I get that `Python.Python.3` is installed by `winget`; however, running `python` says the executable is missing.

`winget uninstall --id Python.Python.3` runs the uninstaller but the uninstaller halts and does not complete.

Is there a way to force the complete removal of a corrupted winget package installation?

Comment: I would just reinstall the package.  I don't know the exact command, but I am sure, there is a way to force install the package so you can uninstall it.  Since this package wouldn't actually use the registry you can also just remove the folder that contains the exectuable.

Comment: @Ramhound the `--force` flag is to ignore hash mismatches. Yes, the un/install runs, however was halting. I posted a solution I found. Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you.   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/upgrade#options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary: `winget` thought `Python.Python.3` was still installed because of a `regedit` key sticking around, hence why `winget list python` reports it being installed. The uninstaller was a remnant from a previously malformed uninstallation (most likely from the same reason a `regedit` key was still existing).

Solution: Removing the `Python.Python.3` package's `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` `regedit` (Registry Editor) key resulted in allowing to re-install the package via `winget install --id Python.Python.3`.

Comment: The key is empty. I had to delete the application via `appwiz.cpl` and it's finally gone.

Comment: @MartinBraun did you remove the empty key before uninstalling?

Comment: almost stock Windows, never touched the registry. But the machine was off for a while, I tried to uninstall `vim.vim` which I installed months ago. The key was entirely empty in the registry, but gVim was still listed in `appwiz.cpl`. There was a CDN change at `winget` that might be the culprit for the initial issues, I had to reinstall `winget`, but the package was still broke.

Comment: @MartinBraun please try deleting the empty key. Not sure if there was a command you were able to run via `appwiz.cpl`, if so could you please provide it? For me deleting the listing in `appwiz.cpl` resulted in running the uninstaller which halts.